# Power BI. Replace "Blank" values with 0, but it's not null from Database

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I connect to Data from Stored Procedure not directly a table from Database so I'm not sure that's why I cannot use Script like

```
RiskCount = IF( ISBLANK( [My column] ), 0, [My column])
```

It's a warning `cannot find name [My column]`

My data from the database looks like

[image]

When data showed up that's made company 1 value c = "Blank"

I want to replace it with "0"

I'm not sure if Power BI can do something like this or if I should edit from the database?

Answer (score 1):

The blanks in the column are likely an empty string `""` rather than a null.

Try doing replacing values like @Aldert described, but leave the first box empty with 0 in the second box so you get M code like this:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"",0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"})
```

Notice the `""` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is in the Query editor. Press: Edit Queries.

[image]

Now select the table and column you want to change the values for and press: Replace Values.

[image]

You get a popup, first field null, second 0.

Comment: i have to try this already. but it's not work cuz I don't have row that's have "Null" values

Comment: So if your value is "Blank", you can put that in the first field. It can also be "", an empty string. Concept stays same, you need the replace function.

Comment: Hi Albert. Sorry for follow up question, but is there a way to force PBI to import properly empty cells (with "") as Blanks? I have like 40 numeric columns in excel with some cells empty. I must import them as blanks (not zeros, it is important to distinguish valid zeros and blanks).

Answer (score 0):

In the Power Query Editor(Advanced Editor)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{.........................
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,each _[Desired column for replacement],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"}),
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```